# zlib format : beginning 2 bytes

Tags: zlib, deflate

I read https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt. Still I have some doubts.
It's mentioned that the `CINFO` value can't be more than 7, but in one of my inputs to the zlib `inflate()` function I have `0x68de` as the first two bytes. I am getting uncompressed data without any error from zlib. Here `0x68`'s first four bits are `0110`, second four bits are `1000`, which means `CINFO` is `8`. I think I am missing something here. Can anyone explain me about these beginning two bytes (`0x68de`) clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for `0x68`, CINFO is `6` and CM is `8`. CM is bits 0 to 3, which are the low four bits, and CINFO is bits 4 to 7, which are the high four bits. Section 2.1 clearly describes the notation used in the document, and which bits are which.